# Silverlight 4.0: Setting an Image Source to an .ico

Tags: image, silverlight, silverlight-4.0

Is there a workaround on this or is this possible in silverlight?

my image is not displaying.

```
<Image Source="http://localhost/TempWS/Images/mtdb.ico" Height="60" Width="60"/>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The Silverlight Image control supports only PNG and Jpeg images out-of-the-box.